# Domain: .com or separated?

Tags: top-level-domains

I have a brand name. In the example I will use `bestsite` (the actual brandname is stands from two parts, too: a short adjective and a noun what is a TLD, too). Which one should I use as Domain?

- `best.site`
- `bestsite.com`

Why?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question?  [Which domain wiser to “SEO-ed” and why?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/111022/which-domain-wiser-to-seo-ed-and-why)

Answer (score 1):

In the SEO world, you need google or any other search engine to recognise your brand and, most importantly, the topics, products or terms associated with your brand. How would you gain the authority to rank for certain terms if google or any other search engine can’t learn about your brand and what is your brand all about?

TLDs are there to help you define the purpose of your brand in the online world. Also, behind each TLDs there is controversy, legal disputes and industry boards discussing them, take for example .adult TLD.

Ideally when your brand is planning to go online you need your TLD to support your online activities. If you are selling products online it will be easier to people to recognise that when you use .com. The very same brand could have a separate .deals website to sell products on sale or have a .blog to comunícate to the brand audience. But always above all you are always recognised as a brand. Here your brand has a blog, a bargain and an online store.

Most of the time your brand name will collide with other peoples brands, or reserved names. Here you have to be very careful not to confuse even more people and search engines. if Best in Best.site is somebody else brand or is a prohibited term, you are in trouble.

Dominos pizza does not need dominos.pizza, they are recognised as a brand. Now imaging in the problem you are if you legitimately Own a series of food recipe books named “dominos” and you are planning to buy and rank dominos.pizza to talk about your pizza recipes.

By using best.site you are confusing both users and search engines, it will take them some time to learn that your brand is actually “best site”.

I will highly recommend making your brand loud and clear and associate your brand with an online purpose leveraging TLDs. You do that once, and you are free to use any TLD you want. I am pretty sure that Procter and Gamble will take my advise too ;)...

Comment: As well, semantically speaking, I am not sure that TLDs help. So myawesomewebsite.com will be understood completely where as myawsoesomeweb.site could potentially drop the term site from the semantic clues. So it really depends upon what the actual domain name would be and no hypothetical domain name can really answer this question. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc I wanted to say what you said as well but could not find a way to explain it. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Anytime Mate!!!